# If pure states are separated by some distance, then our algebra is commutative

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let A be an unital C∗algebra where there exists a $δ > 0$ such that for any pair of distinct pure states $ϕ_1, ϕ_2$ on $A$ we have $|ϕ_1 − ϕ_2| ≥ δ$. Show that this assumption already implies that A is commutative.

The hint is to consider : $U(t)=e^{ita}$ for some hermitian element $a\in A$.

I honestly don't know where to get started with this one, and the hint made it more confusing as I am not sure why that would help.

Comment: Here's a guess at the approach: if $A$ is non-commutative, then (I suspect) there exist elements $a,b$ where $a$ is Hermitian and $[a,b] \neq 0$. If $\rho$ is a pure state for which $\rho([a,b]) \neq 0$, then (I suspect) $\rho_t(x) = \rho(U(t)xU(-t))$ defines a family of states, which means that no such $\delta$ exists.

Comment: Hi, i was wondering where do we get the existence of a state such that p[a,b] not equal 0?

Comment: First, note that you can use Latex in the comments. In this case, `$\rho([a,b]) \neq 0$` becomes $\rho([a,b]) \neq 0$. Second, I'm not sure; all of this is based on a hunch informed by how things work in the nicest possible $C^*$ algebras. I suspect that there is some kind of existence result you can use here along the lines of Hahn-Banach

Comment: Ok I finished the problem. We showed that the commutator is in the null space of every pure state. The existence that $\rho([a,b]) \neq 0$ is obvious because we can decompose it into a hermitian real and imaginary part and there always exists pure state where the image of a specific hermitian element is nonzero.

Comment: Great! Glad that worked out